# What installation key software is well suited for Visual Basic or C# apps?

Tags: .net, key, registration

So I am getting ready to wrap up another project in VB and C# (written in Visual Studio 2008). Now I want to have the software only run in full version mode if the user enters a valid registration key value (like xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx). What software are on the guru's list using which I can manage the registration key generation and integration with the application once sold to the end user?

Feedback is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a loot at the [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/) tool. It provides many features and most probably also a key check plugin (or at least the option to make one yourself) for your installation.
Though I have only used it for a simple setup so far.